# ⊢φ→(((ψ→φ)→δ)→δ)

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

I solved this exercice but I don't know if it's correct. The solution is on the following image:

[solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dddcO.jpg)

Comment: Are you sure? Can I do the implication introduction on line 4?

Comment: The implication introduction rule says that I need to have a subproof where I start from an A and get B to introduct the implication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost. Line 4 should instead be a repeat of $\phi$ (you should have a repeat rule; otherwise you need to pull an ugly trick like introducing $\phi \land \phi$ and then elimiting the conjunction again). Then, on line 5, you should conclude the subproof that started with introducing $\psi$ and derive $\psi \to \phi$. Then, your proof continues as you have written it.

Comment: So it should be something like this https://i.gyazo.com/8ca7e974f20a818f809cc705d515c4f2.jpg right?

Comment: Exactly! $\,\,\,$